# MeteorJs and MongoDB - find where

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor, where-clause

I am building simple app using MeteorJS and MongoDB. I want to return all documents in collection where typeOfLiq  'field' is "aqua". How to do that ?

I have tried but like this but it don't work:

```
Liq.findOne({ typeOfLiq : 'aqua'});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`findOne` returns only one record, you need use [find](http://docs.meteor.com/#/basic/Mongo-Collection-find), like this

```
Liq.find({ typeOfLiq : 'aqua'}) ....
```